# Is ".exe" the only extension of executable program in Windows OS?

Tags: windows, exe, executable, file-extension

I found every process running on my computer has .exe extension on task manager.

Someone said that batch file (.bat) and bytecode (maybe .class) are also executable program, but I think they are just a file running by other executable program (.bat - cmd.exe, .class - JVM, .cpl - rundll32.exe) according to what I saw on task manager

[image: task manager picture]

Is ".exe" the only extension of executable programs in Windows OS?

Comment: That depends entirely on how you define "executable program". If you're asking about "real" / "native" programs that are _directly executable machine code with its own entrypoint_ that's loaded directly by the OS kernel, then no, `.exe` files are not alone: there's also the much, much older `.com` (DOS-style) executables, and programs loaded into other programs (i.e. `.dll` files). In .NET 5, for example, all "exe" programs are actually compiled to a `.dll` file that's loaded by a stub `.exe`.

Comment: as a note: a file extension does not denote the format of the file.
A file can be renamed from "foo.exe" to "foo.html" and it would be still an executable

Comment: By chance, are you writing some code that is trying to block unsafe file extensions from opening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about executing commands then all the extensions in the `%PATHEXT%` environment variable can be run without specifying the extension. For example *.bat, *.vbs... are all *"executable"* in that sense

```
> echo %pathext%
.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
```

If it's about binary executables then Windows doesn't care about the extension of executable files. It just checks the format and if it's a supported binary format then it'll be run. Modern Windows uses PE format which starts with the `MZ` magic number so if you create a *.TXT file with `MZ` at the beginning and run it in cmd then it'll actually be [treated as an executable file](https://superuser.com/q/619921/241386). In fact many files in the System32 folder like *.SCR, *.CPL... are also PE files and still run when we double click on them. And even *.COM files in modern Windows apps are also PE files. The *.COM extension is only for differentiating with another *.EXE of the same app, but with priority in running because *.COM is put before *.EXE in `%PATHEXT%` by default as can be seen above:

- [What would be the reason for WinSCP using a ".com" instead of ".exe"?](https://superuser.com/q/1584296/241386)
- [Executables in Visual Studio: devenv.com/devenv.exe](https://web.archive.org/web/20040427000009/http://blogs.msdn.com/junfeng/archive/2004/02/06/68531.aspx)

Windows 10 [wsl](/questions/tagged/wsl) (not [wsl-2](/questions/tagged/wsl-2)) even supports running Linux ELF executables directly and they of course doesn't have any extension by default. Since [wsl-2](/questions/tagged/wsl-2) the file is run inside the VM instead of directly under Windows kernel like in [wsl](/questions/tagged/wsl)

Depending on Windows version it may support many more executable formats. The complete list is

- Raw binary instructions in old *.com format
- [NE *.exe format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Executable)
- [PE *.exe format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable)
- [MZ *.exe format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS_MZ_executable)
- [ELF format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format)

And they don't depend on the extension either except for the raw *.COM file

Comment: Don't forget `.msi`. installer packages can have executable code inside.